# Не получается подключить библиотеку fyne (Golang)

Tags: golang

Не получается подключить fyne к go, с модулями сделал все вроде верно, сам файн тоже встал, Mingw тоже стоит.
При компиляции кидает много ошибок и ничего не работает

[image: go mod]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Пакет `fyne.io/v2/app` тянет за собой гору пакетов. Для их установки вам нужно в корне вашего проекта выдать команду `go mod tidy`.

В результате на консоли вы увидите что-то вроде такого:

```
go: downloading github.com/gopherjs/gopherjs v1.17.2
go: downloading github.com/godbus/dbus/v5 v5.1.0
go: downloading github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify v1.5.4
go: downloading honnef.co/go/js/dom v0.0.0-20210725211120-f030747120f2
go: downloading fyne.io/systray v1.10.1-0.20230312215936-7f71b037e260
go: downloading github.com/stretchr/testify v1.8.0
go: downloading github.com/fyne-io/gl-js v0.0.0-20220119005834-d2da28d9ccfe
go: downloading github.com/fyne-io/glfw-js v0.0.0-20220120001248-ee7290d23504
go: downloading github.com/fyne-io/image v0.0.0-20220602074514-4956b0afb3d2
go: downloading github.com/go-gl/glfw/v3.3/glfw v0.0.0-20221017161538-93cebf72946b
go: downloading golang.org/x/image v0.0.0-20220601225756-64ec528b34cd
go: downloading github.com/fredbi/uri v0.1.0
go: downloading github.com/go-text/typesetting v0.0.0-20221212183139-1eb938670a1f
go: downloading github.com/goki/freetype v0.0.0-20220119013949-7a161fd3728c
go: downloading github.com/srwiley/rasterx v0.0.0-20210519020934-456a8d69b780
go: downloading github.com/go-gl/gl v0.0.0-20211210172815-726fda9656d6
go: downloading golang.org/x/mobile v0.0.0-20211207041440-4e6c2922fdee
go: downloading github.com/go-gl/glfw v0.0.0-20190409004039-e6da0acd62b1
go: downloading github.com/srwiley/oksvg v0.0.0-20220731023508-a61f04f16b76
go: downloading github.com/yuin/goldmark v1.4.13
go: downloading github.com/tevino/abool v1.2.0
go: downloading github.com/davecgh/go-spew v1.1.1
go: downloading gopkg.in/yaml.v3 v3.0.1
go: downloading github.com/pmezard/go-difflib v1.0.0
go: downloading github.com/jsummers/gobmp v0.0.0-20151104160322-e2ba15ffa76e
go: downloading github.com/benoitkugler/textlayout v0.3.0
go: downloading golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20220722155237-a158d28d115b
go: downloading gopkg.in/check.v1 v1.0.0-20200227125254-8fa46927fb4f
go: downloading github.com/niemeyer/pretty v0.0.0-20200227124842-a10e7caefd8e
go: downloading github.com/kr/text v0.1.0
go: downloading golang.org/x/text v0.6.0
go: downloading github.com/benoitkugler/textlayout-testdata v0.1.1
```

а файл `go.mod` серьезно изменится:

```
module fyneGUI

go 1.19

require fyne.io/fyne/v2 v2.3.3

require (
    fyne.io/systray v1.10.1-0.20230312215936-7f71b037e260 // indirect
    github.com/benoitkugler/textlayout v0.3.0 // indirect
    github.com/davecgh/go-spew v1.1.1 // indirect
    github.com/fredbi/uri v0.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify v1.5.4 // indirect
    github.com/fyne-io/gl-js v0.0.0-20220119005834-d2da28d9ccfe // indirect
    github.com/fyne-io/glfw-js v0.0.0-20220120001248-ee7290d23504 // indirect
    github.com/fyne-io/image v0.0.0-20220602074514-4956b0afb3d2 // indirect
    github.com/go-gl/gl v0.0.0-20211210172815-726fda9656d6 // indirect
    github.com/go-gl/glfw/v3.3/glfw v0.0.0-20221017161538-93cebf72946b // indirect
    github.com/go-text/typesetting v0.0.0-20221212183139-1eb938670a1f // indirect
    github.com/godbus/dbus/v5 v5.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/goki/freetype v0.0.0-20220119013949-7a161fd3728c // indirect
    github.com/gopherjs/gopherjs v1.17.2 // indirect
    github.com/jsummers/gobmp v0.0.0-20151104160322-e2ba15ffa76e // indirect
    github.com/pmezard/go-difflib v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/srwiley/oksvg v0.0.0-20220731023508-a61f04f16b76 // indirect
    github.com/srwiley/rasterx v0.0.0-20210519020934-456a8d69b780 // indirect
    github.com/stretchr/testify v1.8.0 // indirect
    github.com/tevino/abool v1.2.0 // indirect
    github.com/yuin/goldmark v1.4.13 // indirect
    golang.org/x/image v0.0.0-20220601225756-64ec528b34cd // indirect
    golang.org/x/mobile v0.0.0-20211207041440-4e6c2922fdee // indirect
    golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20220722155237-a158d28d115b // indirect
    golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20220722155257-8c9f86f7a55f // indirect
    golang.org/x/text v0.6.0 // indirect
    gopkg.in/yaml.v3 v3.0.1 // indirect
    honnef.co/go/js/dom v0.0.0-20210725211120-f030747120f2 // indirect
)
```